# Drill Through not working in SpagoBI server in birt report

Tags: birt, business-intelligence, spagobi, drillthrough

[image]

**This is the setting of the hyperlink in birt report**

The script used to compute the param is as follows:

```
if (params["idContratto"].match(row["contract_number"].toString()) == null){
    if (params["idContratto"].value == "abc"){
        row["contract_number"].toString();
    }
    else{
        params["idContratto"].value + "," + row["contract_number"].toString();
    }
}
else{
    if (params["idContratto"].length == row["contract_number"].length){
        "";
    }
    else{
        temp = params["idContratto"];
        temp = temp.replace(row["contract_number"].toString(), "");
        if (params["idContratto"].indexOf(row["contract_number"].toString()) == 0){
            temp = temp.replace(",","");
        }
        else{
            if (params["idContratto"].split(",").length == 2){
                temp = temp.replace(",","");
            }
            else if (temp.length == params["idContratto"].indexOf(row["contract_number"].toString())){
                temp = temp.substring(0,temp.length-1);
            }
            else{
                temp= temp.replace(",,",",");
            }
        }
        temp;
    }
}
```

`Drill -through` feature in birt report in spagoBI.. I have created a birt report using drill- through in spagoBI studio, It is running fine there, while deploy it on server. It is showing the error

> -An error has occurred. Retry later. If the problems persists, contact the system administrator.

The url which is shown on the hyperlink is

`"GET /SpagoBIBirtReportEngine/run?__report=%2FD%3A%2FAll-In-One-S‌​pagoBI-5.1.0_2101201‌​5%2Fbin%2FRevenueDet‌​ails.rptdesign&idCon‌​tratto=77&__overwrit‌​e=true HTTP/1.1" 404 687.`

Comment: We can achieve this through sub-report

Comment: I am facing this same issue. @dhS have you any idea how to use drillthrough on SpagoBI server?